# How to change default audio input device programatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am looking for a way to set/change default input device inside my application. I have several different recording devices and it is very anoying to go into the control panel and change default recording device. I was looking around and I did not find anything that could help me with the problem. Application is written in c# and it is targeted for Windows Vista / Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can now (actually for quite some time already) be done very easily using the [AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio).

Simply create a new `CoreAudioController`:

```cs
var controller = new AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.CoreAudioController();
```

Get hold of the desired device using its GUID:

```cs
var device = controller.GetDevice(Guid.Parse(...));
```

And lastly set it as the default playback device:

```cs
controller.DefaultPlaybackDevice = device;
```

*Note: this answer was also posted [under this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1555156/8649828).*

Comment: I don't really need this anymore but since you provided an answer after 13 years you do need a thumbs up. I also tried the package and it works as expected.

Comment: I tried that in my app. The very first line var controller = new AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.CoreAudioController(); goes in and start throwing exceptions inside of it and ruturns a minute later but exceptions keep displaying: Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.dll

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to do this in Vista/7 AFAIK.

For a media center launch thing I created, I had to open the control panel and send keys to the dialog, a big ugly hack, but it's the best you can do. (Or run .net reflector on media center (It is able to change it, using undocumented calls))

Comment: Opening control panel is not an option and I dont need it for media center, but tnx for suggestion.

Comment: Opening the control panel and automating the dialog is your only legal option

Comment: @Matthias Vance http://blogs.msdn.com/larryosterman/archive/2008/07/11/whatever-happened-to-wave-out-mix.aspx#8769290 see the last comment by Larry

Comment: You are right, I was confused by the answer giving in the other SO thread (user replying that it would work on Windows 7).

Answer (score 0):

If you had Windows XP, [apparently](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic2436.html), you can do this by editing the registry. The key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper\Playback` contains the name of the current default playback device.