# C# How to programatically change the playback device

Tags: c#, windows-7, audio, playback

How can I programatically change the default audio device on a vista / win 7 system? Using C# or a Win API call?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334076/how-to-change-default-audio-input-device-programatically except input vs output device, either way, there is no API for it on Vista+ unless you want to decompile media center and find the undocumented stuff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The WinMM API should provide the functionality that you request.

You would use the DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET message, which is sent with waveOutMessage() function.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909789.aspx

However, if you are trying to send the waveform sound out yourself, you should look at the WinMM.Net library.

http://winmm.codeplex.com

Comment: All I need to do is change the sound device on Windows, so that all audio routes through that device. Essentially I have a lot of sound devices on my system, and I want to replace the default sys tray app, so that I don't need to right click , open the device manager each time I need to switch a device. Will this API do this?

Comment: Yes, You can set the default audio playback device in XP with the DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET message, which is sent with waveOutMessage().  This doesn't work in Vista.  I am researching.

Comment: Thanks, I think this last link will work, it should port to win 7 hopefully!

Comment: Love that last link!  It's been driving nuts in Win7 having to launch the Playback devices dialog every time I want to switch from headphones to speakers, and vice-versa.  Much easier now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Ecyrb how exactly did you do that ? WinMM.net doesn't seem to have waveOutMessage functionality. In fact native library import for waveOutMessage is surrounded with #if false preprocessor directive.

Comment: Jonathan Sampson removed the link to http://www.vistaaudiochanger.com/ because it's inactive.  That sucks.  I didn't play with WinMM.net.

Comment: In fact `DRVM_MAPPER_PREFERRED_SET` doesn't work even on XP, [it returns](http://www.microsoft-questions.com/microsoft/Win32-DirectX-Audio/30558445/how-to-send-waveoutmessage-drvmmapperpreferredset-from-net-pro.aspx)  `MMSYSERR_INVALPARAM`. And documentation that you linked to clearly states it's for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

This can now (actually for quite some time already) be done very easily using the [AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio).

Simply create a new `CoreAudioController`:

```cs
var controller = new AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio.CoreAudioController();
```

Get hold of the desired device using its GUID:

```cs
var device = controller.GetDevice(Guid.Parse(...));
```

And lastly set it as the default playback device:

```cs
controller.DefaultPlaybackDevice = device;
```

Comment: I get error CS0200: Property or indexer 'AudioController<CoreAudioDevice>.DefaultPlaybackDevice' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: Okay so the API has changed but I can't get playbackDevice.SetAsDefault() to work either.  Always returns false.

Comment: @KenNetherland I'd suggest you open an issue on their GitHub page then, StackOverflow comments are usually not the best place to find answers to problems like these ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the `AudioSwitcher` constructor to be extra slow in my case.

I suggest using the ["CoreAudio"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/CoreAudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista) API for managing audio devices.

Here is a current wrapper library [available on NuGet.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreAudio/)
https://github.com/morphx666/CoreAudio/tree/master

**Set device:**

```
public static void SetDefaultDevice(string id) {
    MMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator(Guid.NewGuid());
    MMDevice device = deviceEnum.GetDevice(id);
    deviceEnum.SetDefaultAudioEndpoint(device);
}
```

**Get devices**

```
public static MMDeviceCollection GetAudioDevices() {
    MMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnum = new MMDeviceEnumerator(Guid.NewGuid());
    return deviceEnum.EnumerateAudioEndPoints(DataFlow.Render, DeviceState.Active);
}
```