# How to play sound in a specific sound card

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, audio, soundcard

I'm developping in an application in Csharp and I want to read a sound file in an external sound card,is there a function which give me the possibility to play sound using the name of the sound card and the name  of the audio file .
So if I want to create 3 buttons and I have 3 sound cards and each button is related to a sound card (for example button1 is related to sound card1 ...) which code can help me to play an audio file in the specific sound card ??? Please give me a code,because I'm preparing a general alarm  and such code will help me alot.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe there's a way to target output to a specific audio device on-the-fly. You may find my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675786/how-can-i-notify-my-application-that-the-default-sound-playback-device-has-change) interesting. It accomplishes something similar to what you are trying to achieve, albeit in a somewhat more roundabout manner. (It's *extremely* unusual that one computer has more than one sound card, much less three.)

Comment: Also see [this question for Windows XP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115667/change-playback-device-programatically-xp/4117384#4117384), and [this one for Windows Vista and later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555156/c-how-to-programatically-change-the-playback-device).

Comment: @Cody Gray: It's not that uncommon. Even a single low-end/on-board sound card often allows switching to more than one output device (e.g. S/PDIF vs Speakers). USB headsets are quite common also.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way of doing this within .net framework. But you can use the direct sound api:

[DirectSoundEnumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundenumerate%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find available devices and then use the guid of the desired device in [DirectSoundCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.directsoundcreate8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Please, do not change the default device of the PC by messing around with the registry (or at all). This would be a major annoyance for your users.

[Here](http://www.eastcoastgames.com/directx/chapter2.html)'s some sample code for playing a sound in DirectX natively.

You could check out Managed DirectX and/or XNA. It may make life easier for you by providing you with a managed wrapper for DirectSound.

Comment: @Cody Gray,@Ben Schwehn:Thank you very much for replying but yesterday I found a solution with NAudio and i think that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Didn't know NAudio before!

Comment: @nicolecastel how can i achieve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240612/how-transfer-system-mic-audio-stream-to-attached-device-mic-audio-stream?noredirect=1#comment63908020_38240612 this to xchange sound between two sound cards.